# How to invoke environmental variables while connecting to DB2 database using python

Tags: python, db2, environment-variables

I have saved the DB2 username and DB2 password as 'DB2_USER' and 'DB2_PASS' in .bashrc(linux). And, I'm trying to invoke them in my python program to connect to DB2 database.

.bashrc content:

```
export DB2_USER="my_username"
export DB2_PASS="my_password"
```

My python code snippet:

```
db_user = os.environ.get('DB2_USER')
db_password = os.environ.get('DB2_PASS')

conn = ibm_db.connect('DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};DATABASE=<my_db>;HOSTNAME=<my_hostname>;PORT=50000;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=db_user;pwd=db_password','','')
```

while executing the above code , I'm getting the below error. May I know for any other alternative ways?

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test.py",
> line 38, in 
> conn = ibm_db.connect('DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};DATABASE=<my_db>;HOSTNAME=<my_hostname>;PORT=50000;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=db_user;pwd=db_password','','')
> Exception: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30082N  Security processing failed
> with reason "24" ("USERNAME AND/OR PASSWORD INVALID").  SQLSTATE=08001
> SQLCODE=-30082

Comment: @mao Yes, I printed the db_user and db_password . And, I can see the actual values printed. Btw, my password has special chars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My earlier code literally took `db_user` & `db_pass` as username and password. Constructing the connection string using concatenation helped.

```
conn = ibm_db.connect('DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};DATABASE=<my_db>;HOSTNAME=<my_hostname>;PORT=50000;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;'+';UID='+db_user+';pwd='+db_pass,'','')
```